# Remove element from multi nested Json array object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I want remove the particular element from nested `json` array. 
The below json object has root node as EE with nested child Nodes & Packages. I want to delete the node `id = 7`. Is it possible to do that?

```
$scope.data = { 
       "id": 1, "parentNodeId": null, 
       "nodeName": "EE",  "magCode": "EE", 
       "childNodes": [{ 
              "id": 2, 
              "parentNodeId": 1, 
              "nodeName": "Child 1", 
              "magCode": "EE", 
              "childNodes": [], 
              "packages": [] 
           }, 
           { 
              "id": 4, 
              "parentNodeId": 1, 
              "nodeName": "Child 2", 
              "magCode": "EE", 
              "childNodes": [{ 
                     "id": 5, 
                     "parentNodeId": 4, 
                     "nodeName": "Child 21", 
                     "magCode": "EE", 
                     "childNodes": [], 
                     "packages": [] }], 
              "packages": [{ 
                     "id": 6, 
                     "parentNodeId": 4, 
                     "nodeName": "Child Package 2", 
                     "magCode": "EE", 
                     "childNodes": null, 
                     "packages": null 
                   },
                   { 
                     "id": 7, 
                     "parentNodeId": 4, 
                     "nodeName": "Child Package 3", 
                     "magCode": "EE", 
                     "childNodes": null, 
                     "packages": null 
                   }
                ]
       }],
       "packages": [{ 
             "id": 8, 
             "parentNodeId": 1, 
             "nodeName": "test", 
             "magCode": "EE", 
             "childNodes": null, 
             "packages": null 
       }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library such as lodash to remove the unwanted items:

```
 var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var evens = _.remove(array, function(n) {
  return n % 2 == 0;
});

console.log(array);
// → [1, 3]

console.log(evens);
// → [2, 4]
```

[lodash remove documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#remove)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically, this is like tree structure with childnodes and packages as different icons in front end. I want to delete dynamically based on selected node id by external button.

Comment: shouldnt be an issue, create a function that takes the id as a param and you can then pass it to lodash to filter out the selected item. With the binding in Angular your UI will be updated automatically. Lodash supports filtering of sub collections so it should be a perfect fit. Here is an example of what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096988/lodash-how-do-i-use-filter-when-i-have-nested-object