# Find keys in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I receive multiple JSONs from an API (17 API calls with `Promise.all()` ). For example

```
[
  {
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value,
    values: [
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value,
    values: [
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value,
    values: [
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
      {
        key: value,
        key: value,
        key: value,
        keyIWant: value
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I really have no idea to get the key I want (and to get it on a more generic approach). So far my attempts have been

```
static _findKey(nestedData) { 
    const result = [];
    const buffer = [];
    for (const prop in nestedData) {
        const value = nestedData[prop];
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            buffer.push(Class._findKey(value)); 
        }
        if (prop === "keyIWant") { // key would be an argument from the function if it'd worked 
             result.push(value);   // doesn't work because of recursive call?
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and

```
static _findKey(projects) { // 
    return projects.forEach(project => {
        return project.values.forEach(projectValue => {
            return projectValue.key;
        });
    });
}
```

Do you have some more ideas? I'm still learning JavaScript and thus want a clean and comprehensive solution, but couldn't build one by myself.

Comment: if you know the path why not use lodash to filter and get what you need? [Example here on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096988/lodash-how-do-i-use-filter-when-i-have-nested-object)

Comment: look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I know the path for this specific example, but there may be other examples I don't the path. My goal was to build one generic function to reuse it the whole time, just by giving the key as argument and get all corresponding values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below function to get all values stored at the key you specify:

```
function getKeyValues(arr, key) {
    return arr.reduce((a,b) => {
        let keys = Object.keys(b);
        keys.forEach(v => {
            if (Array.isArray(b[v])) a = a.concat(getKeyValues(b[v], key));
            if (v === key) a = a.concat(b[v]);
        });
        return a;
    }, [])
}
```

Call with

```
getKeyValues(arr, "keyIWant")
```

```js
let arr = [{
    key: 'foo',
    values: [{
        key: 'value',
        keyIWant: 'keyIWant1'
      },
      {
        key: 'value',
        keyIWant: 'keyIWant2'
      }, {
        key: 'value',
        keyIWant: 'keyIWant3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'foo',
    values: [{
        key: 'value',
        keyIWant: 'keyIWant4'
      },
      {
        key: 'value',
        keyIWant: 'keyIWant5'
      }, {
        key: 'value',
        keyIWant: 'keyIWant6'
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getKeyValues(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    let keys = Object.keys(b);
    keys.forEach(v => {
      if (Array.isArray(b[v])) a = a.concat(getKeyValues(b[v], key));
      if (v === key) a = a.concat(b[v]);
    });
    return a;
  }, []);
}


console.log(getKeyValues(arr, "keyIWant"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for many data processing tasks like yours. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you could answer your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (input) => objectScan(['**.keyIWant'], { rtn: 'value' })(input);

const arr = [{ key: 'foo', values: [{ key: 'value', keyIWant: 'keyIWant1' }, { key: 'value', keyIWant: 'keyIWant2' }, { key: 'value', keyIWant: 'keyIWant3' }] }, { key: 'foo', values: [{ key: 'value', keyIWant: 'keyIWant4' }, { key: 'value', keyIWant: 'keyIWant5' }, { key: 'value', keyIWant: 'keyIWant6' }] }];

console.log(find(arr));
/* =>
[ 'keyIWant6',
  'keyIWant5',
  'keyIWant4',
  'keyIWant3',
  'keyIWant2',
  'keyIWant1' ]
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)