# How to filter nested array with values from another nested array using array.filter and array.some etc

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code which I am using to filter one nested array with values from another nested array, but I am looking for the more fastest method.

```
  const length = this.addedStateItems.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if (this.addedStateItems[i].cities.length > 0) {
            const tempCity: Array<BWCity> = [];
            for (let k = 0; k < addedStates.length; k++) {
              for (let l = 0; l < addedStates[k].Cities.length; l++) {
                const city = this.addedStateItems[i].cities.find(item =>
                  item.name.toUpperCase().split(' ').join('_') === addedStates[k].Cities[l].CityName
                );
                if (city) {
                  tempCity.push(city);
                }

              }
            }
            this.addedStateItems[i].cities = tempCity;
          }
      }
```

JSON sample is as below:

```
this.addedStateItems = [
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Alabama",
    "code": "AL",
    "sequence": 2,
    "access": 2,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Alaska",
    "code": "AK",
    "sequence": 3,
    "access": 3,
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Arizona",
    "code": "AZ",
    "sequence": 4,
    "access": 4,
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Arkansas",
    "code": "AR",
    "sequence": 5,
    "access": 5,
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "California",
    "code": "CA",
    "sequence": 6,
    "access": 6,
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Colorado",
    "code": "CO",
    "sequence": 7,
    "access": 7,
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Connecticut",
    "code": "CT",
    "sequence": 8,
    "access": 8,
    "id": 8
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Delaware",
    "code": "DE",
    "sequence": 9,
    "access": 9,
    "id": 9
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "District of Columbia",
    "code": "DC",
    "sequence": 10,
    "access": 10,
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Florida",
    "code": "FL",
    "sequence": 11,
    "access": 11,
    "id": 11
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Georgia",
    "code": "GA",
    "sequence": 12,
    "access": 12,
    "id": 12
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Hawaii",
    "code": "HI",
    "sequence": 13,
    "access": 13,
    "id": 13
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Idaho",
    "code": "ID",
    "sequence": 14,
    "access": 14,
    "id": 14
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Illinois",
    "code": "IL",
    "sequence": 15,
    "access": 15,
    "id": 15
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Indiana",
    "code": "IN",
    "sequence": 16,
    "access": 16,
    "id": 16
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Iowa",
    "code": "IA",
    "sequence": 17,
    "access": 17,
    "id": 17
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Kansas",
    "code": "KS",
    "sequence": 18,
    "access": 18,
    "id": 18
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Kentucky",
    "code": "KY",
    "sequence": 19,
    "access": 19,
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Louisiana",
    "code": "LA",
    "sequence": 20,
    "access": 20,
    "id": 20
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Maine",
    "code": "ME",
    "sequence": 21,
    "access": 21,
    "id": 21
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Maryland",
    "code": "MD",
    "sequence": 22,
    "access": 22,
    "id": 22
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Massachusetts",
    "code": "MA",
    "sequence": 23,
    "access": 23,
    "id": 23
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 9
          }
        ],
        "name": "MI Generic",
        "code": "MIG",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 10
          }
        ],
        "name": "Port Huron",
        "code": "POH",
        "id": 9
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [],
        "name": "Hudson",
        "code": "HUD",
        "id": 31
      }
    ],
    "name": "Michigan",
    "code": "MI",
    "sequence": 24,
    "access": 24,
    "id": 24
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Minnesota",
    "code": "MN",
    "sequence": 25,
    "access": 25,
    "id": 25
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Mississippi",
    "code": "MS",
    "sequence": 26,
    "access": 26,
    "id": 26
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 1
          }
        ],
        "name": "Kansas City",
        "code": "KCM",
        "id": 29
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 2
          }
        ],
        "name": "St Louis",
        "code": "STL",
        "id": 30
      }
    ],
    "name": "Missouri",
    "code": "MO",
    "sequence": 27,
    "access": 27,
    "id": 27
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Montana",
    "code": "MT",
    "sequence": 28,
    "access": 28,
    "id": 28
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Nebraska",
    "code": "NE",
    "sequence": 29,
    "access": 29,
    "id": 29
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "New Hampshire",
    "code": "NH",
    "sequence": 31,
    "access": 31,
    "id": 31
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "New Jersey",
    "code": "NJ",
    "sequence": 32,
    "access": 32,
    "id": 32
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "New Mexico",
    "code": "NM",
    "sequence": 33,
    "access": 33,
    "id": 33
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 3,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 4,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 5,
            "sequence": 1
          }
        ],
        "name": "New York City",
        "code": "NYC",
        "id": 11
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 2
          },
          {
            "systemId": 2,
            "sequence": 1
          }
        ],
        "name": "Yonkers",
        "code": "NYY",
        "id": 12
      }
    ],
    "name": "New York",
    "code": "NY",
    "sequence": 34,
    "access": 34,
    "id": 34
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "North Carolina",
    "code": "NC",
    "sequence": 35,
    "access": 35,
    "id": 36
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "North Dakota",
    "code": "ND",
    "sequence": 36,
    "access": 36,
    "id": 37
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 12
          },
          {
            "systemId": 3,
            "sequence": 3
          },
          {
            "systemId": 4,
            "sequence": 3
          },
          {
            "systemId": 5,
            "sequence": 3
          }
        ],
        "name": "OH Generic",
        "code": "OHG",
        "id": 13
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 3,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 4,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 5,
            "sequence": 1
          }
        ],
        "name": "OH RITA",
        "code": "OHR",
        "id": 14
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 2
          },
          {
            "systemId": 3,
            "sequence": 2
          },
          {
            "systemId": 4,
            "sequence": 2
          },
          {
            "systemId": 5,
            "sequence": 2
          }
        ],
        "name": "OH CCA",
        "code": "CCA",
        "id": 15
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 3
          }
        ],
        "name": "Akron",
        "code": "AKR",
        "id": 16
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 4
          }
        ],
        "name": "Cincinnati",
        "code": "CIN",
        "id": 17
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 6
          }
        ],
        "name": "Columbus",
        "code": "COL",
        "id": 19
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 7
          }
        ],
        "name": "Toledo",
        "code": "TOL",
        "id": 20
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 8
          }
        ],
        "name": "Springfield",
        "code": "SPR",
        "id": 21
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 9
          }
        ],
        "name": "Wyoming",
        "code": "WYO",
        "id": 22
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 10
          }
        ],
        "name": "Indian_Hill",
        "code": "IHL",
        "id": 23
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 11
          }
        ],
        "name": "Mansfield",
        "code": "MAN",
        "id": 24
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 12
          }
        ],
        "name": "Crestline",
        "code": "CRE",
        "id": 25
      }
    ],
    "name": "Ohio",
    "code": "OH",
    "sequence": 37,
    "access": 37,
    "id": 38
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Oklahoma",
    "code": "OK",
    "sequence": 38,
    "access": 38,
    "id": 39
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Oregon",
    "code": "OR",
    "sequence": 39,
    "access": 39,
    "id": 40
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 1
          }
        ],
        "name": "PA Generic",
        "code": "PAG",
        "id": 26
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 2
          },
          {
            "systemId": 2,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 3,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 4,
            "sequence": 1
          },
          {
            "systemId": 5,
            "sequence": 1
          }
        ],
        "name": "Philadelphia",
        "code": "PHI",
        "id": 27
      }
    ],
    "name": "Pennsylvania",
    "code": "PA",
    "sequence": 40,
    "access": 40,
    "id": 41
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Rhode Island",
    "code": "RI",
    "sequence": 41,
    "access": 41,
    "id": 42
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "South Carolina",
    "code": "SC",
    "sequence": 42,
    "access": 42,
    "id": 43
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Tennessee",
    "code": "TN",
    "sequence": 44,
    "access": 44,
    "id": 45
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Texas",
    "code": "TX",
    "sequence": 45,
    "access": 45,
    "id": 46
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Utah",
    "code": "UT",
    "sequence": 46,
    "access": 46,
    "id": 47
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Vermont",
    "code": "VT",
    "sequence": 47,
    "access": 47,
    "id": 48
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Virginia",
    "code": "VA",
    "sequence": 48,
    "access": 48,
    "id": 49
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "West Virginia",
    "code": "WV",
    "sequence": 50,
    "access": 50,
    "id": 51
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Wisconsin",
    "code": "WI",
    "sequence": 51,
    "access": 51,
    "id": 52
  }
]
```

Second JSON:

```
addedStates = [
  {
    "StateName": "DISTRICT_OF_COLUMBIA",
    "Cities": []
  },
  {
    "StateName": "COLORADO",
    "Cities": []
  },
  {
    "StateName": "ALABAMA",
    "Cities": []
  },
  {
    "StateName": "OHIO",
    "Cities": [
      {
        "CityName": "AKRON"
      },
      {
        "CityName": "CINCINNATI"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "StateName": "NEW_YORK",
    "Cities": [
      {
        "CityName": "YONKERS"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

After filtering first JSON with second JSON I expect this:

```
result = [
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Alabama",
    "code": "AL",
    "sequence": 2,
    "access": 2,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "Colorado",
    "code": "CO",
    "sequence": 7,
    "access": 7,
    "id": 7
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [],
    "name": "District of Columbia",
    "code": "DC",
    "sequence": 10,
    "access": 10,
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 2
          },
          {
            "systemId": 2,
            "sequence": 1
          }
        ],
        "name": "Yonkers",
        "code": "NYY",
        "id": 12
      }
    ],
    "name": "New York",
    "code": "NY",
    "sequence": 34,
    "access": 34,
    "id": 34
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "cities": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 3
          }
        ],
        "name": "Akron",
        "code": "AKR",
        "id": 16
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "citySequences": [
          {
            "systemId": 1,
            "sequence": 4
          }
        ],
        "name": "Cincinnati",
        "code": "CIN",
        "id": 17
      }
    ],
    "name": "Ohio",
    "code": "OH",
    "sequence": 37,
    "access": 37,
    "id": 38
  }
]
```

Comment: as it comes to deep filtering, you can try with `lodash` .
here is an example :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096988/lodash-how-do-i-use-filter-when-i-have-nested-object

Comment: Hi, Thanks but my filtering condition is from a nested JSON. the above example is not like that.